# Smarty - scope of dates

Tags: arrays, smarty

I'm creating smarty3 code that shows the expected delivery date of a product depending on the current time and day of the week.

```
Tuesday   -> <14:00 Friday    - 14:00 Monday)
Wednesday -> <14:00 Monday    - 14:00 Tuesday)
Thursday  -> <14:00 Tuesday   - 14:00 Wednesday)
Friday    -> <14:00 Wednesday - 14:00 Thursday)
Monday    -> <14:00 Thursday  - 14:00 Friday)
```

I'm thinking of storing the list in an array where the Key is the day of the week and value is the scope.

How can I check if the current sever date corresponds with any of the scopes and how should I store the scopes in the array so that I can check the range?

Comment: Shouldn't the last row start with Monday?

Comment: You're right, I've fixed the table. Still don't know how to store scopes thou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php:

```
$expected = time()-14*3600+2*86400;
if(date('w',$expected) ==6){
  $expected+=86400;
}
if(date('w',$expected) ==0){
  $expected+=86400;
}
print date('l',$expected);
```

In smarty:

```
{$expected = $smarty.now() -14*3600+2*86400}
{if date('w',$expected) ==6}
  {$expected = $expected + 86400}
{/if}
{if date('w',$expected) ==0}
  $expected+=86400;
  {$expected = $expected + 86400}
{/if}
{$expected|date_format:%A}
```